# jQuery: Get ID Of Closest Text Input

Tags: jquery, alert, attr

I have a text input field, next to this there is a button. When I click this button, I want alert() to show me the ID of the input field. This is my code

```
<tr>
   <td>Item <?php echo $i; ?>:</td>
   <td>
       <input type="text" name="course_include_1" class="regular-text" /> <input type="button" class="button" id="DeleteItem" value="Delete Item" />
    </td>
</tr>
```

And this is my jQuery code:

```
    $("#DeleteItem").live("click", function() {
        //$(this).parents("tr").remove();
        alert($(this).prev().attr("id"));
    });
```

Why is this not working?

**Edit:** I should add that the there is also a "Add" button which creates a new input field along with the delete button next to it. The code for this looks like this:

```
$("#AddItem").live("click", function() {
            Count++;
            $('<tr><td>Item ' + Count + ':</td><td><input id="asdadad" name="course_include_' + Count + '" type="text" class="regular-text" /> <input type="button" class="button" id="DeleteItem" value="Delete Item" /></td></tr>').appendTo(TableRow);
        });
```

The goal is to click on the delete button next to the newly created field and show its ID in an alert() box. And that's not working.

Comment: there is no id added for input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Q: Why is this not working?
A: The input has no id attribute

**Edit**

Now you have many elements with `id="DeleteItem"` which may well cause 'unexpected' browser behaviour (eg. mess up the binding). Use a class instead, changing this in the line when you append the new item:

```
class="button" id="DeleteItem"
```

to this:

```
class="button DeleteItem"
```

...and in the event binding change this:

```
$("#DeleteItem").live("click", function() {
```

to this:

```
$(".DeleteItem").live("click", function() {
```

or even to this (it is recommended to use `.on()` instead of `.live()` , see [first text paragraph here](http://api.jquery.com/bind/)):

```
$(document).on('click','.DeleteItem', function() {
```

That might resolve things

**Edit 2**

ps. I would also make a unique `id` for each input element, eg. `... id="asdadad"'+Count+' ...` or move it to the class if they are supposed to be the same for every item added

Comment: I've specified my problem, please see my original post.

Answer (score 1):

Because the input doesn't have an id attribute set e.g.

```
<input id='myInput' type="text" name="course_include_1" class="regular-text" />
```

Comment: You're right, but the whole code is like this: There is one input field with a delete button next to it. At the bottom, there is a button which creates another input field along with the delete button. This looks like this:

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("#DeleteItem").live("click", function() {
    alert($(this).parent().find(".regular-text").attr("id"));
});
```

**Update**

The problem is because you are appending an element with a duplicate `id` attribute. Change the `#DeleteItem` to use a class instead.

Comment: Tested this already. I always get the message "undefined" in the box.

Comment: Well you need to set the `id` attribute on the `input` element. I assumed you'd just forgotten to add this to your example case.

Answer (score 0):

it's not answering your question but it will DELETE the row all together if you do this...

```
<input type='button' value='delete' onclick="$(this).parents('tr').remove();" />
```

parents (vs parent) will do a 'find' but upward until it finda the `<tr>` holding the row... then remove will 'delete' it.

PS: If you have multiple tow, and multiple delete button they need UNIQUE id's or jq get confused sometimes.